# Parametrization and line integration

Tags: integration, line-integrals

$$\vec{B} = \frac{cos(\alpha)}{p^2}e_p + (\frac{sin(\alpha)}{p^2}+\frac{1}{ap})e_\alpha + 0e_z$$

Calculate the line integral $$\int_C \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{r}$$, where C is parameterized by

$$ \vec{r} = (bcos(s),bsin(s),b)$$$$ b>0$$ $$s: 0\rightarrow2\pi$$

I have tried writing $d\vec{r} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}ds$, and rewriting $\vec{B}$ in only s, but I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I assume that $\mathbf{r}$ is written in cartesian coordinates $\mathbf{r} = b\cos s\;\mathbf{e}_x + b\sin s\;\mathbf{e}_y + b\;\mathbf{e}_z$. What is the relation between the vectors $\{\mathbf{e}_\alpha, \mathbf{e}_p\}$ and  $\{\mathbf{e}_x, \mathbf{e}_y, \mathbf{e}_z\}$?

Comment: B is given in cylindrical coordinates, that's all the information I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{r} }{{\rm d}s} = -b\sin s\;\mathbf{e}_x + b\cos s\;\mathbf{e}_y = b \mathbf{e}_\alpha \tag{1}
$$

where $\mathbf{e}_\alpha$ is the unit tangential vector in cylindrical coordinates. And $\mathbf{B}$ can be written as

$$
\mathbf{B} = \frac{\cos \alpha}{\rho^2} \mathbf{e}_\rho + \left(\frac{\sin \alpha}{\rho^2} + \frac{1}{a \rho} \right) \mathbf{e}_\alpha \tag{2}
$$

From Eqns (1) and (2):

$$
{\rm d}\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{B} = {\rm d}s\frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{r} }{{\rm d}s}\cdot\mathbf{B} = {\rm d}s\; b \left.\left(\frac{\sin \alpha}{\rho^2} + \frac{1}{a \rho} \right)\right|_{\rho = b, \alpha = s} = {\rm d}s\; \left(\frac{\sin s}{b} + \frac{1}{a} \right)
$$

We then arrive to

$$
\int_C {\rm d}\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{B} = \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}s\; \left(\frac{\sin s}{b} + \frac{1}{a} \right) = \frac{2\pi}{a}
$$